The edit queue is full at the moment - should I just wait, or is this a bug?
This morning I asked a question about a tool, which might yes or no be accessible via Visual Studio. As I'm working with Visual Studio 2022, I decided to add the Visual Studio version in order to get a more exact answer, but Visual Studio 2022 is apparently not a tag for this website yet.
So I decided to add the tag, and I wanted to edit the tag wiki, but this seems not to work because of the following error message:

I had this error message this morning, and I'm still having it this afternoon. Is everybody working that much, flooding the edit queue, or is no one working on emptying the edit queue? (As it's friday, I would opt for the second one :-) )

I cannot say much about the edit queue, but I think this tag "Visual Studio 2022" is not a good fit, neither for your question, nor for this site. On Software Engineering - other than on Stack Overflow - we focus on conceptual programming questions, which makes most questions tool agnostic, and definitely agnostic from the specific IDE's version. ...

Moreover, I think your question does not need any kind of Visual Studio tag - it is actually an IDE agnostic question (just because you are working with VS does not change this).

... I think I will remove the VS-2022 tag and leave it up to you if you want to remove the VS tag as well.
